# Angular animation between components doesn't work with a video element that is playing

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

So I have been trying to figure out how to solve this but without any luck. We have an Angular 11 application where animation between components is a crucial part (think signage software). One of our components that is being animated have a video element that has autoplaying enabled. Everything works as expected except for the animation when the video is playing. In that case the component containing the video element appears instantly.

Repository showing the problem:
https://github.com/stefanedberg/angular-animate-video

Miscellaneous info:

- Angular 11.0.3
- Doesn't work in latest Chrome or Firefox on Windows 10/Big Sur.
- Node v12.20.1 and NPM 6.14.10.

Comment: Please give an example or demo code. It will be easier to check. If you want you can provide a sample code in stackblitz too. Best wishes :)

Comment: Hi Linker! I created a repository reproducing the error and it's in my post above, or are you missing something? Here it is: https://github.com/stefanedberg/angular-animate-video